# How to get the message from the qmgr in webshere mq?

Tags: ibm-mq

Hi I created two queue managers, I put the message in remote queue(PVN.TO.NAG) in qmgr(pvn)
but when I get the message from the other qmgr(nag) localqueue(LQ.NAG) . but it shown no more messages?

```
-bash-3.00$ /opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqsput PVN.TO.NAG pvn
    Sample AMQSPUT0 start
    target queue is PVN.TO.NAG
    hi this is pvn

    Sample AMQSPUT0 end
    -bash-3.00$ /opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqsget LQ.NAG nag
    Sample AMQSGET0 start
    no more messages
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Have you linked both `pvn` and `nag` queue managers using sender & receiver channels and transmit queue?

2) Verify the remote queue definition `PVN.TO.NAG` is correct, i.e it points to `LQ.NAG`

3) Check if `nag` queue manager has a dead letter queue(DLQ) set. If it is already set, check if your message is ending up there because the `nag` queue manager is not able to route the message to a queue on remote queue manager. If the message is there, then it will contain reason why the message ended up in DLQ.

Comment: When I put the message it will goes to store in Dead letter queue. with the reason code 2055(MQRC_Q_NOT_EMPTY). pls provide the solution. thanks in adv

Comment: InfoCenter link (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fm12580_.htm) says that 2055 occurs while closing a permanent dynamic queue but the queue still has some messages. But your test scenario does not seem to use permanent dynamic queue. It may be helpful if you could post details of your configuration like (1) Interconnection between the two queue managers, (2) local queue and remote queue definitions and so on.